# Simple way how to handle UI events inside fragment (onClick, ...)

Tags: android, rx-android, android-databinding

I am trying to use last features from android - Kotlin, mvvm, architecture components, jetpack, databinding, one activity - many fragments approach with new navigation graph, but I am struggling with handling UI events in Fragments

**In activity it is simple with kotlin-android-extensions**
In XML I create a Button like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="clicked"/>
```

and in Activity I just write

```
fun clicked(view : View){

}
```

**That's perfect, but unfortunately does not work in Fragment. Yes it is possible to still handle event in Activity and send it to fragment but that's ugly.**

**Next option is to use an interface,**

```
public interface MyClickCallback{
    void onLoginButtonClick();
}
```

implement it in fragment.
In xml it looks like this:

```
    <variable
        name="clickCallback"
        type="com.test.MyClickCallback" />
```

then in fragment's onCreateView I have to set clickCallback to the fragment and finally I can use it

```
@Override fun onLoginButtonClick() {

}
```

Problem I have with this is to declare interface and on each new UI event enhance this interface and update fragment which implements it

**Next option is RxView.clicks what looks really great with all its features.** For example:

```
RxView.clicks(mSearchBtn)
        .throttleFirst(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map(aVoid -> mSearchEdit.getText().toString().trim())
        .filter(s -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(s))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(s -> {

          KeyBoardUtil.closeKeybord(mSearchEdit,
              SearchActivity.this);
          showSearchAnim();
          clearData();
          content = s;
          getSearchData();
        });
```

Problem here is that I have to bind it to the UI component - mSearchBtn. I do not want this :-). I do not want to have any UI component in fragment unless I really have to. I am always communicating with layout file via variables declared in layout like this

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="items"
        type="java.util.List" />
</data>
```

I would love to bind it to variable declared in the XML which is set in Button

```
android:onClick="myclick"
```

But I did not find the way how to do it.

Anybody can help me maybe with other simple and nice options ?

Answer (score 0):

In your databinding layout create a variable that is of type View.OnClickListener:

```
<variable
    name="onClickListener"
    type="android.view.View.OnClickListener" />
```

Set it to your View like this:

```
<View
    ...
    android:onClickListener="@{onClickListener}"
    ... />
```

In your Fragment create the onClickListener and set it to the variable:

```
binding.onClickListener = View.OnClickListener { 
    /* do things */
    /* like getting the id of the clicked view: */
    val idOfTheClickedView = it.id
    /* or get variables from your databinding layout: */
    val bankAccount = binding.bankAccount
}
```

Or in Java:

```
binding.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /* do things */
            /* like getting the id of the clicked view: */
            Int idOfTheClickedView = view.getId();
            /* or get variables from your databinding layout: */
            Object bankAccount = binding.getBankAccount()
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is nice option, but it is not possible to pass any additional information from layout, like id, .. or ?

Comment: If you want to get the id of the view that was clicked you can simply call v.getId() inside your OnClickListener that you defined in your Fragment. I updated my answer to show you how you can get the id. What other additional information do you want to pass?

Comment: I mean any other Object, anything like when I do it via interface, for example android:onClick="@{() -> callback.onSubmitClick(bankAccount)}"

Comment: I'm guessing bankAccount is a variable defined inside your databinding layout? 
Then you should consider using a ViewModel, which you instantiate inside your Fragment and set as a variable in your databinding layout. Then you can simply set android:onClickListener="@{() -> viewModel.submitClick(bankAccount)}". Learn more about ViewModels here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel .

Comment: Another solution without ViewModels is to simply get the bankAccount variable in the Fragment by calling binding.getBankAccount() inside your OnClickListener, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> it is simple with kotlin-android-extensions

It is indeed simple, but you are currently not using it to its fullest potential.

Setting click listeners in Kotlin is very easy, look:

```
fun View.onClick(clickListener: (View) -> Unit) {
    setOnClickListener(clickListener)
}
```

And now thanks to synthetic imports in Kotlin-Android-Extensions:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="@string/click_me"/>
```

and

```
import kotlinx.synthetic.blah.* // something like that

// Activity:
override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(bundle)
    setContentView(R.layout.blah)

    myButton.onClick {
        // handle click event 
    }
}

// Fragment:
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, bundle: Bundle?) = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blah, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View) {
    super.onViewCreated(view)

    myButton.onClick {
        // handle click event 
    }
}
```

---

But if you really want to use databinding and layouts for this, then set the callback lambda and inside the databinding layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="activity" type="com.acme.MainActivity"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOpenSecondView"
            android:text="Click me for second view!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> activity.startNextActivity(v)}" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```